# How To Check If Property Has Any Relationships?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-data, nsobject

I have an entity `Session`.  In my view, entity `Exercise` may be added to `Session`.

Before I save, I want to check if there are any relationships with `Session`, so if not, I will delete the object before saving it.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Edit:

```
- (void)createSession
{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *dateComponentsForToday = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:self.picker.date];
    [dateComponentsForToday setHour:0];
    [dateComponentsForToday setMinute:0];
    [dateComponentsForToday setSecond:0];
    NSDate *targetDateBegins = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComponentsForToday]; 
    NSDate *targetDateEnds = [targetDateBegins dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60 * 60 * 24 - 1)];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(timeStamp >= %@ && timeStamp <= %@)", targetDateBegins, targetDateEnds]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]];
    NSLog(@"timeStamp >= %@ && timeStamp <= %@", targetDateBegins, targetDateEnds);

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Fetch error: %@", error);

    if ([results count])
    {
        session = (Session *)[results objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    else
    {
        session = (Session *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        session.timeStamp = self.picker.date;
    }

    NSSet *filteredExercisesFromSession = [session.exercises filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"name == %@",selectedExerciseName]];
    if ([filteredExercisesFromSession count] > 0)
    {
        self.exercise = [filteredExercisesFromSession anyObject];
    }

    [fetchRequest release];
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [setsTableView reloadData];
}

-(IBAction)createSet
{    
    NSSet *filteredExercisesFromSession = [session.exercises filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"name == %@",selectedExerciseName]];

    if ([filteredExercisesFromSession count] > 0)
    {
        self.exercise = [filteredExercisesFromSession anyObject];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"exercise does not already exist");
        self.exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
        self.exercise.name = selectedExerciseName;
        self.exercise.muscleGroup = muscleName;
        [session addExercisesObject:exercise];
    }

    Set *set = (Set *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Set" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    set.weight = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:weightSelected2];
    set.reps = [NSNumber numberWithInt:repSelected];
    set.timeStamp = self.picker.date;
    [self.exercise addSetsObject:set];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil; 
    [setsTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Clarification: Do you mean that a new Session object is always being created (in the first if-block) even if one already exist? You should explain what you expect to happen and then what actually happens. We don't know what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: Sorry, let me explain better.  So first if block checks if a `Session` exists, if it does, fetch it, otherwise create it.  And the end of all the code, I want to check if there are any `exercise` object for the a particular `Session` with timeStamp as today's date.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** What an unclear question...! Next time please post code first.

Your `NSPredicate` might be wrong, try this :

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(date >= %@) AND (date <= %@)",
                                   startDate, endDate];
```

**ENDOFEDIT**

---

Just fetch the object to ensure it exist or not.

If your relation is `Session 1->n Exercise` then you should have an *inverse relationship* like `myExercise.session` to check (fetch) easily. Or you can just use plain `NSFetchRequest`...

Also note that there are 'cascade' delete facilities in CoreData, but I doubt It could help in your (child entity) case.

W/o any more code/details it is hard to figure what's your issue and how to solve it.

Comment: Dear Vincent, I have added my code in the question.  The problem I am facing here is that I keep getting a blank Session object for today's date every time I load the view.  This is what I am trying to get rid of.

Comment: Unforetunately, I am having the same problem of a Session keep being created for today's date along with the correct session with the date that was manually selected.